# PyTest-Django Failing on missing django_migration table

Tags: python, django, testing, database-migration, pytest

I'm trying to add pytest-django to my current pytest3/Django1.7 environment.

Currently we have not been using the plugin and have been suffering from shared state between certain tests

Everything seems to visually look good and the tests seem to pass until the end when I get the following error messages:

```
request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function 'test_filter_recurring_outside_sync_window'>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request):
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django.

        This will dynamically request the ``db`` or ``transactional_db``
        fixtures as required by the django_db marker.
        """
        marker = request.keywords.get('django_db', None)
        if marker:
            validate_django_db(marker)
            if marker.transaction:
                getfixturevalue(request, 'transactional_db')
            else:
                getfixturevalue(request, 'db')

ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:376:


self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x11976a478>
query = 'SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"', params = ()

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       OperationalError: no such table: django_migrations

ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:485: OperationalError
```

I tried creating the table with `ensure_schema` in the `conftest.py`.
I've tried every option of `--nomigrations` and `--create-db` to `pytest`.

I'm guessing it's a weird configuration problem I have with a legacy system, but I'm not sure where to start looking. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: have you tried makemigrations and migrate for each of the app separately?
this might resolve your issues at times

Comment: Are you using something like `py.test /path/to/django/project --nomigrations --ds=myproject.settings.test`? What's the command you're running?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like may be an issue with migration.

Running `./manage.py schemamigration research --auto` shows that most of the fields don't have any defaults specified.

Next, you then run `./manage.py schemamigration research --init` followed by `./manage.py migrate research`

This worked for me after I created the table:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

NOTE: Don't forget to run python makemigrations first, i.e. `python manage.py makemigrations {name of the app where patients model is}`

> > **Helpful tips:** There is a table generated by `django` called `django_migrations` which keeps track of what migrations have
> >     been
> >     applied. If you delete your `migrations`, re-generate them and try to
> >     `migrate` without deleting the records from the table, then `django` will
> >     think it already applied them. You should never delete your
> >     migrations, as it will cause django to get confused.
> >
> > You can skip the migrations step if you are actively developing If you are actively developing and want to skip the entire `migrations`
> >     system you can, but once you start using `migrations`, never delete
> >     them. Here is what I use while developing a new project:
>
> ```
> dropdb mydb && createdb mydb && python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python manage.py loaddata initial
> ```
>
> First, it drops the database and all data. Then it creates an empty
>   one. The `--run-syncdb` generates the schema and the `loaddata` loads
>   data from a [fixtures file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/).
>
> So, if you are still developing and can delete all your data and move
>   what you care about to a fixtures file, then you can delete all your
>   migration folders. You then can run the command above each time you change your
>   model.